Confidence interval for heat equation solution
The following is an excerpt from book Ralph C. Smith - Uncertainty Quantification: Theory, Implementation, and Applications.

Exercise 9.1. Consider the linearly parameterized problem
$$
\Upsilon=X Q+\varepsilon,
$$
where $Q=\left[Q_1, \ldots, Q_p\right]$ and $\varepsilon=\left[\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n\right]$ are random vectors and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is a deterministic and known matrix. We assume that $\varepsilon \sim N(0, V)$, where $V=\sigma^2 I_{n \times n}$, and that the mean $\bar{q}$ and covariance matrix $V_q$ for $Q$ are known. Use the results from Exercise 4.5 to establish mean and covariance relations for $\Upsilon$ analogous to (9.5).
Exercise 9.5. Consider the heat equation with constant diffusivity $\alpha$ and $f(t, x)=$ $T_{\ell}=T_R=0$. It was established in Exercise 3.1 that a finite difference discretization with an $N+1$ spatial gridpoint yields the vector relation
$$
\mathcal{T}^{j+1}=A^{j+1} \mathcal{T}^0,
$$
where $\mathcal{T}^j=\left|T_{1, j}, \ldots, T_{N-1, j}\right|^T$ and the $(N-1) \times(N-1)$ matrix $A$ is defined in (3.51). Here we take $\alpha=2, x_i=-1+i h$ with $h=\frac{1}{4}$ and consider the initial heat distribution $\mathcal{T}^0$ to be a random vector with mean $\mathcal{T}^0=\sin \left[\frac{\pi}{2}\left(x_i+1\right)\right], i=1, \ldots, 7$, and covariance matrix $V=0.1^2 I_{7 \times 7}$. The temporal stepsize is taken to be $k=0.01$ to satisfy the stability constraint
$$
k \leq \frac{h^2}{2 \alpha}
$$
Let $\mathcal{T}^{\prime}$ denote the solution at $t_f=\frac{1}{3}$, and consider the statistical model
$$
\mathcal{T}^f=\mathcal{A} \mathcal{T}^0+\varepsilon
$$
where $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A}^{j+1}$ and the measurement error is iid and $\varepsilon \sim N\left(0,0,05^2 I_{7 \times 7}\right)$. Use the results of Exercise 9.1 to compute credible and prediction intervals for $\mathcal{T}^f$, and discuss their relation to the distribution for $\mathcal{T}^0$ in the context of the diffusive nature of the heat equation.

I'm trying to solve Exercise 9.5, Exercise 9.1 is just here for reference and I've already solved it. I've already computed $\mathcal{A}$, my question is that I don't understand how to compute the credible and prediction intervals for $\mathcal{T}^f$. For that I would need a new observation, but $\mathcal{A}$ isn't a design matrix (with a column of 1's and so on). How do I do that?

Please define the terms you want to use and tell us which book is this.

What do you mean by "terms you want to use"

The main idea is that it is not the estimation of the parameters that we are doing, but rather we are sending the uncertainty that we know through the system. We are provided with a linear equation for the final temperature field:
$$\mathcal{T}^f = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{T}^0 + \varepsilon$$
The $\mathcal{T}^0$ in this case represents a random initial temperature vector which has a predetermined mean and covariance, while $\varepsilon$ is a measurement error vector, also with a known mean and covariance matrix. The matrix, which is called the finite difference matrix, $\mathcal{A}$, is derived from the solution of the heat equation in a finite difference discretization.
The purpose of this project is to find the credible and prediction intervals for $\mathcal{T}^f$ by calculation. By proving a few results like those in Exercise 9.1, we can derive the following distribution for $\mathcal{T}^f$:
$$\mathcal{T}^f \sim N(\mathcal{A}\bar{\mathcal{T}}^0, \mathcal{A}V_{\mathcal{T}^0}\mathcal{A}^T + V_\varepsilon)$$
We understand from this that $\mathcal{T}^f$ is normally distributed with a mean vector $\bar{\mathcal{T}}^f = \mathcal{A}\bar{\mathcal{T}}^0$ and a covariance matrix $V_{\mathcal{T}^f} = \mathcal{A}V_{\mathcal{T}^0}\mathcal{A}^T + V_\varepsilon$. It is important to note that both mean and covariance can be calculated from the known data.
To make credible intervals for the individual temperatures $T_i^f$, we consider the normal distribution of each of the $T_i^f$. The mean of each $T_i^f$ is the $i$-th entry of $\bar{\mathcal{T}}^f$ and the variance is the corresponding diagonal entry of $V_{\mathcal{T}^f}$. By applying the 95% normal quantiles, we get intervals of the form
$$\bar{T}^f_i \pm 1.96\sqrt{V_{\mathcal{T}^f(i,i)}}$$
Prediction intervals, on the other hand, indicate the uncertainty in (a) new (one) measurement of the true $\mathcal{T}^f$. The basic practice is to add both the variance of $\mathcal{T}^f$ and the measurement error. The 95% prediction intervals are:
$$\bar{T}^f_i \pm 1.96\sqrt{V_{\mathcal{T}^f(i,i)} + V_\epsilon(i,i)}$$
In this scenario, the variance of the measurement error is presented as a constant of $0.05^2$, which makes the formula easy to use:
$$\bar{T}^f_i \pm 1.96\sqrt{V_{\mathcal{T}^f(i,i)} + 0.05^2}$$
The spreading or radiation of heat in the equation implies that initial temperature dominated regions are less distinct over time, which will be mirrored in the credible intervals, which are narrower than those of the initial temperature distribution. Additionally, the prediction intervals are far more extensive than the credible intervals, thus compensating for the additional uncertainty introduced by a new observation. The difference here is that the prediction intervals cover both the uncertainty in the underlying mean of $\mathcal{T}^f$ and the variability of a single new measurement from that distribution. As a result, the prediction interval extends to a broader range of possible values compared to a credible interval, which is only reflective of the uncertainty in the parameters of the distribution itself. In brief, the algorithm employed in this work is rather the moving of the uncertainty among initial conditions to the uncertainty in the final result than it is about the parameter estimation.
